# PHP string comparison returning true when they don't match

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Why do the following string comparisons return true?

I am using Laravel framework 4.2, the Form::select compares the option value using this method and it's find matches that shouldn't be.

```
  public function testStringComparison1()
  {
    $value = '8000003E-1408739159';
    $selected = '8000010E-1434656519';
    $b = false;
    if ((string) $value == (string) $selected) {
      $b = true;
    }
    $this->assertFalse($b);  // this fails, $b == true
  }

  public function testStringComparison2()
  {
    $value = '8000008E-1408740949';
    $selected = '8000010E-1434656519';
    $b = false;
    if ((string) $value == (string) $selected) {
      $b = true;
    }
    $this->assertFalse($b);  // this fails, $b == true
  }
```

Comment: Always type juggling.  Use `===`

Comment: Thanks for response.  To follow-up and better understand, what 'type' could PHP compare these as to determine them equal?

Comment: They are string representations of floats: `echo (float)$value;
    echo (float)$selected;`  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the types match as well, not just the values (weird stuff with type casting), use `===`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php